# How to better analyze runtime of complex nested loops?

Tags: runtime, big-o

When you have nested for-loops where the amount of loops for the nested one changes each time, what is the easiest approach to analyze the total runtime? It's hard for me to conceptualize how to factor in the changing max value since I've only ever analyzed nested loops where the max was out of N, which led to a pretty simple O(n^2) runtime. Should I make a summation and use that?

**For Example:**

```
int val = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < val; j++) {
        val++;
    }
}
```

My intuition tells me this is 2^n, but I have no practical way of really proving that

Answer (score 0):

In general, to find the time complexity of loops, you need to find how many times they execute, as a function of the input. Sometimes it is straightforward, sometimes it is not. You may end up with complex mathematical expressions, and in some cases you may not be able to decide at all.

As for your example, your outer loop would clearly run exactly `n` times. Your inner loop, however, checks its loop condition `j < val`, which the first time is true because `j = 0` and `val = 1`. Then, it increments `val` by `1` on each iteration so it will always be true that `j < val`. Therefore we notice that it is an infinite loop, and your program thus runs in *O(∞)*.

(As a side note, in practice, depending on the language of implementation, eventually `val` may overflow and become smaller than `j`, which will cause the loop to finish. In this case, it only depends on the integer size you are using.)